# javac: file not found (cygwin error)

Tags: java, cygwin, apache-pig, javac

I have followed a tutorial on how to embed pig commands on java. I have installed cygwin and I did all the required setup. I have embedded the program in netbeans and called it idlocal1.
The problem that I have is on cygwin. Basically when I typed (on cygwin) `javac -cp pig.jar idlocal1.java` in order to compile the program, I got the following message:

```
javac -cp pig.jar idlocal1.java
javac: file not found: idlocal1.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Can you please tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the current directory to the classpath explicitly.

```
javac -cp pig.jar\;. idlocal1.java
```

If this does not work, next try to replace the semi-colon to a colon:

```
javac -cp pig.jar:. idlocal1.java
```

If even the above does not work, check whether idlocal1.java exists in the current directory. To be concrete, try to specify the file name with `"./"`.

```
javac -cp pig.jar\;. ./idlocal1.java
```

Comment: I have tried it but unfortunately i still have the same problem

Comment: I updated the answer to add more command lines for you to try.

Comment: I have followed your instructions but I get these errors:            $ javac -cp pig.jar\;. ./idlocal1.java
.\idlocal1.java:10: error: package org.apache.pig does not exist
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
                     ^
.\idlocal1.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
public static void runIdQuery(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile) throws IOException {
                              ^
  symbol:   class PigServer
  location: class idlocal1

Comment: .\idlocal1.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");
    ^
  symbol:   class PigServer
  location: class idlocal1
.\idlocal1.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");
                              ^
  symbol:   class PigServer
  location: class idlocal1
4 errors

Comment: It seems that your first problem "file not found" has been solved, so this question should be closed (and mark my answer as accepted unless you don't like it).

The new error "cannot find symbol" is another different problem. If you post another question about "cannot find symbol", people will help you.